# Mongoose model.save() hangs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on a command-line node script that defines a Mongoose model, then creates a new document using that model, then saves it. But the `.save(function(){...});` method doesn't seem to finish. It saves the document in Mongo, but the script just sits there and doesn't complete. It never returns back to the command prompt:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/mydb');

var schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    street: String
});

var Location = mongoose.model('Location', schema);

var location = new Location({name: "Home", street: "Main Street"});

location.save(function(err){

    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }

    console.log(location);
});
```

The result is in the terminal is:

```
{ __v: 0,
  name: 'Home',
  street: 'Main Street',
  _id: 562b062d0ce456a912ee9559 }
```

But then the terminal just sits there. I have to CTRL+C to get back to the command prompt. Something about the `.save()` method seems to make the script hang... The document does get saved in the database though. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The database connection is still open and listening for events. For the script to end, you need to close it:

```
location.save(function(err){

    if (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }

    console.log(location);
    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Comment: Ah thank you. What is the difference between `close` and `disconnect`?

Comment: mongoose allows you to create multiple connections. I believe `disconnect()` closes all of them, while `close()` is singular.